# Creating large heatmap using highcharts freezes browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am creating a large heat map using highcharts.It works fine  but when there are large numbers of records to generate heatchart for.In that case it freezes broswer and an alert is shown by broser to wait or end page. I have seen few other answers on Stackoverflow which suggest to  change calculation algorithm into something which can be called iteratively and then use timeout() but I am not able to use it in my scenario that how can I make highchart rendering iterative?

How can I prevent it from freezing browser ?

Comment: Can you provide a demo ?

Comment: Why can't you use it in your scenario?

Comment: @Brewal : I am trying to create a demo

Comment: @JonasGrumann : Because I don't know that how does Highchart creates that  heatmap. So  I can't convert it into an iterative solution then.

Comment: @Brewal : you can see highcharts heatmap demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/ .In my case I just have many more values.In which case it freezes browser.

Comment: Have you more definition, or greater time periode ? You should load only piece of data one by one... I mean, if you want to see the whole year, you don't need a good definition, and if you want to see only one month, you don't need the rest of the data

Comment: Actually I have a different code.It works fine till 1200 values on y axis and 200 cols on xaxis.But If I need to generate chart for 4000 values on y axis.In that case it freezes the broeser.I need to show heatmap for compelte data.Which can even contain 10000 point on y axis.

Comment: To prevent the browser from freezing, you have to display less data in highchart on a single time. Maybe you should pre-compute averages of the data, and then display only a more accurate map on zoom, mouseover, or any event you want. Loading to much data is indeed the cause of freezing

Comment: @Brewal : Yeah , you are right. I was just trying to find out if there is any other way to tackle the problem.  Can't we use timeout way.I tried but I am not able to find out to how to use that in this.I can't think of making it iterative.

Comment: Can't you do serverside pre-calculation job with caching and just return a json "as-is" for the highchart ? I think the freezing problem is due to the actual displaying of data, but it could help. But I think you should really go to lower resolution by averaging values.

Comment: When browser gives warning for either allowing or kill script.If I allow it , it generates that heatmap properly.So dislaying of a data is not a problem I think.I can't  take average approach.That data can't be averaged.Means requirement is  to have actual values on graph.

Comment: I see... Really anoying ! Can you provide this demo with the huge amount of data ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts has a lot of loops to render the data, so the only possibility I found is to reduce the amount of data loaded. Loading 10MB+ (often already at 3-4MB) worth of data causes almost every browser to freeze.

I had a similar problem with huge datasets (months of 10 series with 15min data points). What I did was a server sided data aggregation (4h averages) when viewing the whole data set. On zoom I got the actual 15min data points through ajax but only for the visible area with the afterSetExtremes event:

```
events: {
  afterSetExtremes: 'function(event) { 
      if(typeof event.userMin == "undefined") 
          { var a={"min": null, "max": null}; } 
      else 
          { var a={"min": event.min, "max": event.max}; } 
      $.ajax({url:"/user/analyze/intval", method: "POST", 
          data: a, dataType: "json"}).success(function(json) 
          { //update series here }'
}
```

I use the typeof event to determine whether zoom reset was used (to get initial aggregated data again)

I think something similar should solve your problem too. And ask yourself, does it help to have so much data? Very often the visible difference is close to zero even when the original data is heavily aggregated (factor 4-6).